# Remove/disable event listener on subset of features in google.maps.Data class

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, mouseevent, geojson

I am trying to change the icon representation of a feature in a google.maps.Data class so that once a feature has been clicked, the new icon stays until another feature has been clicked. . .all while keeping the `mouseover` and `mouseout` event listeners active for the rest of the features.

I have achieved everything but making the clicked feature icon stay as `wx_click.png` Once I move my mouse off of it, the style reverts (as per the code).  I don't want to remove the `mouseout` or `mouseover` listeners for any of the other features, just the one that has been clicked.

```
/* ~~ Mouseover listener ~~ */
map.data.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    map.data.revertStyle();
    map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
        icon: '/img/wx_mo.png', 
        title: 'weather station',
    })
});

/* ~~ Mouseout listener ~~*/
mouseoutEventListener = map.data.addListener('mouseout', function(event) {
    map.data.revertStyle();
});

/* ~~ Click listener ~~ */
map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {

    map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {icon: '/img/wx_click.png'});

// do other stuff
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In the click-handler:**

store the clicked marker in a variable.
when this variable is not equal to the clicked feature revert the style of the stored feature.

**in the mouseover/mouseout-handlers:**

only change the icon/revert the style of the current feature when the current feature isn't equal to the stored feature.

```
/* ~~ Mouseover listener ~~ */
map.data.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    if(map.get('activeFeature')!=event.feature ){
    map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
        icon: '/img/wx_mo.png'
    });
    }
});

/* ~~ Mouseout listener ~~*/
mouseoutEventListener = map.data.addListener('mouseout', function(event) {
    if(map.get('activeFeature')!=event.feature ){
      map.data.revertStyle(event.feature);
    }
});

/* ~~ Click listener ~~ */
map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
    var activeFeature=map.get('activeFeature');
    if(activeFeature && activeFeature!=event.feature ){
      map.data.revertStyle(activeFeature);
    }
    map.set('activeFeature',event.feature);
    map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
      icon: '/img/wx_click.png'
    });

// do other stuff
});
```

---

**Demo:**

```js
function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: {
      lat: 0,
      lng: 0
    }
  });
  map.data.setStyle({
    icon: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/marker.png'
  });


  /* ~~ Mouseover listener ~~ */
  map.data.addListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    if (map.get('activeFeature') != event.feature) {
      map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
        icon: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/icon_green.png'
      });
    }
  });

  /* ~~ Mouseout listener ~~*/
  mouseoutEventListener = map.data.addListener('mouseout', function(event) {
    if (map.get('activeFeature') != event.feature) {
      map.data.revertStyle(event.feature);
    }
  });

  /* ~~ Click listener ~~ */
  map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
    var activeFeature = map.get('activeFeature');
    if (activeFeature && activeFeature != event.feature) {
      map.data.revertStyle(activeFeature);
    }
    map.set('activeFeature', event.feature);
    map.data.overrideStyle(event.feature, {
      icon: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/markers2/boost-marker-mapview.png'
    });

    // do other stuff
  });

  // Load GeoJSON.
  map.data.addGeoJson({
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [0, 0]
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [1, 1]
      }
    }, {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [-1, -1]
      }
    }]
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```